# Html, Css - Inner div go outside parent, when appear vertical scroll bar

Tags: html, css, scroll

This table (and when I replace table by div) is going outside parent, when vertical scroll exists

### Bug screen

https://i.stack.imgur.com/MSMpE.png

### Demo

http://tuteta.ru:3000/ , push to red button "Bug is here". You will see list of users, and tables of some users is going outside parent.

Answer (score 0):

```css
.parent{
 position:relative;
 height:150px;
 width:200px;
 border:1px solid;
 overflow:auto;
}
.one{
  position:relative;
  display:block;
  height:50px;
  width:100%;
  margin:5px auto;
  background:#600;
  color:gold;
  text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="one">one</div>
  <div class="one">Two</div>
  <div class="one">Three</div>
  <div class="one">Four</div>
  </div>
```